# Excel if statement / Sum of Column

Tags: excel

I'd like to create a formula to say if anything in A column has "Admission" then sum the adjoining B column. I know I could do this cell by cell and sum up the cells, but is it possible to have one text box that can do this by itself?

I'm creating an Expenses page for our honeymoon to see where the money is going. I should be able to see how much we spend on Admission prices, Hotel, etc. But to keep it simple, I didnt want to make a bunch of boxes that has random value in it if I could avoid it. So I created a summary page that has a text box for a specific day. So for September XX, I could select the boxes, and if it has "Admission" in one field (simple reasons A column) then I would like to add the B cell next to it to obtain a sum.

I've looked up everything but can't seem to get it to work. So now, I'm asking for help.

Thank you!

A1 Breakfast - B1 $5

A2 Lunch - B1 $5

A3 Dinner - B1 $5

A4 Admission - B1 $5

A5 Event - B1 $5

A6 Admission - B1 $5

A7 Snack - B1 $5

A8 Event - B1 $5

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the following formula:

```
=SUMIF(A:A, "Admission", B:B)
```

If you put in in a table, and instead of typing the expense type into the forumla, you reference the table column header, you can even copy paste the formula for a quick sum of all types!

[image]

Concidentally, I keep track of my own expenses in the exact same way, using a spreadsheet :p
[image]

(You can do the same thing with `CountIf`, to get the count and calculate the average expense. Min and Max are a little more complicated.)

Comment: Awesome. I feel so dumb. Thank you.

Comment: +1 for neat answer! But so many expenses for Parking while 0$ for Gas, maybe you should consider selling your car.

Comment: @FrancisP Haha, yeah, I had a gas card that year.

Answer (score 2):

This should

```
=SUMIF(A:A,"Breakfast",B:B)
```

and enjoy your honey moon!